# Expected number of vertices of degree k in a random graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

I am wondering what would be the expected number of vertices with degree k in the random graph $G(n,p)$?

What I have gotten so far is:
$$\mathbb{P}(deg(v)=k)=\binom{n-1}{k}p^k(1-p)^k $$
So then the number of vertices with exactly $k$ degrees would be:
$$n\binom{n-1}{k}p^k(1-p)^k$$

I know that it is possible to simplify this more but I am not sure if this is right or how to simplify.

Comment: The first equation is wrong. If you have $k$ successes out of $n-1$ trials, how many failures do you have?

Comment: @Leo should it be $\binom{2k}{k}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment, the first equation is wrong. The probability for exactly $k$ out of $n-1$ edges to exist is

$$
\binom{n-1}kp^k(1-p)^{n-1-k}\;,
$$

so the expected number of vertices of degree $k$ is

$$
n\binom{n-1}kp^k(1-p)^{n-1-k}\;.
$$

No simplification is possible (unless you regard $n\binom{n-1}k=(n-k)\binom nk$ as a simplification).